# Keycloak not working with Oracle client-jre?

Tags: java, keycloak

Is their any restriction that keycloak will work with server-jre only and not with client-jre ?
In my linux machine we have following version installed

```
 /usr/sbin/alternatives --config java

There are 2 programs which provide 'java'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*  1           java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.141-2.b16.el7_4.x86_64/jre/bin/java)
 + 2           /usr/java/jre1.8.0_102/bin/java
```

Then its working fine with openjdk but keycloak not coming up with Oracle **client-jre** and giving this exception

> 2018-03-22 12:30:56,163 ERROR
>   [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread
>   Pool -- 26) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
>       ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
>       ("data-source" => "KeycloakDS") ]): org.jboss.as.server.services.security.VaultReaderException:
>   WFLYSRV0227: Security exception accessing the vault
>           at org.jboss.as.server.services.security.RuntimeVaultReader.retrieveFromVault(RuntimeVaultReader.java:124)
>           at org.jboss.as.server.RuntimeExpressionResolver.resolvePluggableExpression(RuntimeExpressionResolver.java:65)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.ExpressionResolverImpl.resolveExpressionString(ExpressionResolverImpl.java:341)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.ExpressionResolverImpl.parseAndResolve(ExpressionResolverImpl.java:246)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.ExpressionResolverImpl.resolveExpressionStringRecursively(ExpressionResolverImpl.java:143)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.ExpressionResolverImpl.resolveExpressionsRecursively(ExpressionResolverImpl.java:84)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.ExpressionResolverImpl.resolveExpressions(ExpressionResolverImpl.java:66)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.resolveExpressions(ModelControllerImpl.java:868)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.resolveExpressions(OperationContextImpl.java:1269)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.ParallelBootOperationContext.resolveExpressions(ParallelBootOperationContext.java:438)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.AttributeDefinition$1.resolveExpressions(AttributeDefinition.java:619)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.AttributeDefinition.resolveValue(AttributeDefinition.java:683)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.AttributeDefinition.resolveModelAttribute(AttributeDefinition.java:642)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.AttributeDefinition.resolveModelAttribute(AttributeDefinition.java:616)
>           at org.jboss.as.connector.util.ModelNodeUtil.getResolvedStringIfSetOrGetDefault(ModelNodeUtil.java:35)
>           at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.DataSourceModelNodeUtil.from(DataSourceModelNodeUtil.java:178)
>           at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.AbstractDataSourceAdd.secondRuntimeStep(AbstractDataSourceAdd.java:348)
>           at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.AbstractDataSourceAdd$1.execute(AbstractDataSourceAdd.java:133)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:980)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:726)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:450)
>           at org.jboss.as.controller.ParallelBootOperationStepHandler$ParallelBootTask.run(ParallelBootOperationStepHandler.java:386)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>           at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320) Caused by: org.jboss.security.vault.SecurityVaultException:
>   java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default
>   parameters
>           at org.picketbox.plugins.vault.PicketBoxSecurityVault.retrieve(PicketBoxSecurityVault.java:297)
>           at org.jboss.as.server.services.security.RuntimeVaultReader.getValue(RuntimeVaultReader.java:157)
>           at org.jboss.as.server.services.security.RuntimeVaultReader.retrieveFromVault(RuntimeVaultReader.java:110)
>           ... 25 more Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default parameters
>           at javax.crypto.Cipher.checkCryptoPerm(Cipher.java:1026)
>           at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:801)

But same setup working with **open-jdk** without any issue after that i updated the Oracle Java and used **server-jre**

```
[root@ha1 ~]#  /usr/sbin/alternatives --config java

There are 2 programs which provide 'java'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*  1           java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.141-2.b16.el7_4.x86_64/jre/bin/java)
 + 2           /usr/java/jre1.8.0_102/bin/java
```

This time it worked totally fine and keycloak running without any issue .

Comment: That looks like the very common Oracle/Sun crypto-limited-to-128-bits issue, for which there are already about a hundred Qs, except that should apply equally to Oracle/Sun JDK, (client) JRE, AND server-JRE when that exists (last 1.5 years), and 8u161 or 162, or 9, of _any_ of those -- or any OpenJDK since forever -- should fix it.

Comment: Do you mean 8u161 and 162 client-jre fixed this issue ?

Comment: _All_ variants of Oracle 8u161 and 162 (JDK, client JRE, server-JRE) fixed the crypto-limited-policy issue (by making it configurable but default to unlimited), which I think (but cannot be absolutely certain) is the issue you have. (OpenJDK is built differently and never had this problem in any version.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.